# BeautifulSoup: how to get the value of the price from the webpage's source code if there is no id within the source code for the price

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am doing web scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup and wondering if I there is a way of getting the value of a cell when it has no id. The code is as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time 
import datetime


URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Got-Data-MIS-Business-Analyst/dp/B09F319PK2/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=funny+got+data+mis+data+systems+business+analyst+tshirt&qid=1636481904&qsid=257-9827493-6142040&sr=8-1&sres=B09F319PK2%2CB09F33452D%2CB08MCBFLHC%2CB07Y8Z4SF8%2CB07GJGXY7P%2CB07Z2DV1C2%2CB085MZDMZ8%2CB08XYL6GRM%2CB095CXJ226%2CB08JDMYMPV%2CB08525RB37%2CB07ZDNR6MP%2CB07WL5JGPH%2CB08Y67YF63%2CB07GD73XD8%2CB09JN7Z3G2%2CB078W9GXJY%2CB09HVDRJZ1%2CB07JD7R6CB%2CB08JDKYR6Q&srpt=SHIRT"


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14092.77.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.107 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")

title = soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup2.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()


print(title)
print(price)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this page, you have to select the garment size before the price is displayed.  We can get the price from the dropdown list of sizes which is a SELECT with id = "dropdown_selected_size_name"

First let's get a list of the options in the SELECT dropdown:

```
options = soup2.find(id='variation_size_name').select('select option')
```

Then we can get the price say for size 'Large'

```
for opt in options:
    if opt.get('data-a-html-content', '') == 'Large':
        print(opt['value'])
```

or a little more succinctly:

```
print([opt['value'] for opt in options if opt.get('data-a-html-content', '') == 'Large'][0])
```